# Joomla - Open all external links in new tab

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I want to open all external links on my Joomla site in a new browser tab.  Is there any way to do this globally and automatically?

Running Joomla 3.4.3.

Comment: When you say external links, do you mean just anything that someone happens to put in an article? Or are you talking about structered links like those in the Links fields or the link for an RSS feed? I'm assuming you don't have/mean weblinks?

Comment: Yes, all links in articles.  I.e. anytime there's this: `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">stackoverflow</a>` - convert it dynamically to this: `<a target="_blank" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">stackoverflow</a>`.

Comment: It's going to be really slow but you could write a content plugin that would do a regex for the link htemp and then basically push the target attribute in.

Comment: Yes, a content plugin is the way to go imo. I don't think it need to be terribly slow either

Comment: @user3154108 Could you please point me in the general direction - maybe examples or pertinent links?  I'm an experienced programmer (Python, C, Go) but I'm not familiar with Joomla programming nor PHP.  Much appreciated.  Thanks!!

Comment: I'm afraid if you want a plugin, you need to delve a little into extension programming. Plugins are easy (basically an event driven approach), but you should know some joomla conventions. There are some guides on the Joomla Developer Portal you can start with.

Comment: Just look at the load module plugin in the content folder. Just like for that you would need to regex the content body and stick a target="_blank" into any a tags you find.

Comment: @Elin: Thanks for taking a moment.  I'm reasonably adept with Python, Go, Javascript, and C, but I do not know PHP.  I'm just trying to get my consulting site up and running... don't have time to learn PHP and develop my own plugin.  I found a workaround that didn't involve starting from a blank sheet - I modified the ACE X Markdown editor plugin to be able to use a leading "!" in the link text to signify an external link.  That's working OK for me for now.  Thanks again.